# Using a UIButton instead of a UISegmentedControl to control a socket app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uisegmentedcontrol

I found this piece of code and it works great except I want to use a UIButton instead of a UISegmentedControl. See the code below

```
- (IBAction)ToggleLight:(id)sender {

    UISegmentedControl *button = ((UISegmentedControl*)sender);
    long tag = button.tag;

    NSString *response  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"P%ld%@", tag , button.selectedSegmentIndex?@"L" : @"H"];
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[response dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
    [_outputStream write:[data bytes] maxLength:[data length]];

}
```

I am pretty sure I need to change the first line to

```
UIButton *button = ((UIButton*)sender);
```

but I am confused by what to put instead of "selectedSegmentIndex" for a UIButton to have the same effect? I am new to this so I maybe going the wrong direction completely. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here is a [link](http://bitcows.com/?p=249) to where I got the code and the tutorial I am working from.

Comment: It depends on when you want to use @"L" versus when you want to use @"H" in the data you're building.  The segmented control acts -- more or less -- like two buttons and chooses based on which is selected.  If you only have a single button, you need to decide some other way.

Comment: Thanks Philip. So is there no way to have it so when the button is depressed it goes to @"H" and when its released it goes to @"L". In other words the default would be @"L" and the button would toggle it to @"H" when its pressed?

Comment: You can create a NSString property in your class that holds the string you want to use and change it depending on some event.  The part you need to figure out is which event(s) should cause the change.  Normally, a button's action happens when it is released.

Comment: Forgive me If this is straight forward but are you saying that a UIButton cannot really be set up as a momentary switch so that when its first pressed it changes the state and then stays in that state until it is released? So when the button is first pressed it goes @"H" and then when the button is released it goes back to @"L"? Any examples would be a big help!

Comment: You can do it.  Take a look at documentation for `- (void)addTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents` in `UIControl`.  The events can be various kinds of touches and you can add different actions.  I guess what I was saying is, it's not exactly standard but I think you can do it if you need to.

Comment: Can you explain what that code is exactly doing line by line? I am still struggling at figuring out how to implement it with a UIbutton. I feel like I am making it far too complicated and I need an example.